# Retrieve ip address of client who got a connection reset

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have this code which gets the ip of the client when the client closes or loses the connection.

```
char buffer[80]; 
ssize_t bread;
struct sockaddr_in peer;
socklen_t peer_len;

peer_len = sizeof(peer);

memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

bread = read(connectlist[listnum], buffer, 80);
if (bread < 0)
{

if(getpeername(connectlist[listnum],(struct sockaddr *) &peer, &peer_len) == -1){

        perror("getpeername() failed");
    }
            printf("Connection Reset From IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr));

                _Print_To_File(inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr));
                    close(connectlist[listnum]);
                        close(connectlist[listnum]);
                            connectlist[listnum] = 0;

}

if(bread == 0)
{
if(getpeername(connectlist[listnum],(struct sockaddr *) &peer, &peer_len) == -1){
        perror("getpeername() failed");
    }
            printf("Connection Closed From IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr));

                _Print_To_File(inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr));
                    close(connectlist[listnum]);
                            connectlist[listnum] = 0;
}
```

I can get the ip of the client when Connection Closed but When Connection Reset I don't get the ip of the client. I get 0.0.0.0 on connection reset. How can i fix this. thanks,

Comment: The `accept()` done beforhand, would have given you the client address and port.

Comment: So using the struct sockaddr on the accept will give me the ip address of client?.. thanks.

Comment: You need to check `errno` before you go blindly assuming you got a reset. It could be several other things. And why are you closing the socket twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to use the `struct sockaddr` returned by the call to `accept()` done prior to `read()`ing.

Verbatim from `man accept`:

> **int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);**
>
> [...]
>
> The argument addr is a pointer to a sockaddr structure.  *This
>   structure is filled in with the address of the peer socket, as known
>   to the communications layer.*  The exact format of the address returned
>   addr is determined  by
>          the socket's address family (see socket(2) and the respective protocol man pages).  When addr is NULL, nothing is filled in; in this
>   case, addrlen is not used, and should also be NULL.

Comment: But what is the difference? i got the ip on connection close but not on connection reset?

Comment: If the connection had been reset the peer information is gone already. @demic0de

Answer (score 2):

`getpeername()` works only for connected sockets. Once the socket disconnected you'll get `ENOTCONN` error when invoking it. This is why `getpeername()` is sometimes used as a check whether the socket has/is connected.